# Modify framework.dex which is in boot.oat?

Tags: android

I pulled down `boot.oat` from an API22 Android phone. It's Android 5.1 Lollipop which brought the change from Dalvik to ART and is a bit mistified.

As far as I understand, modifying boot.oat is not easy, and permanent, as this file is regenerated whenever a package installation is happening.

Now, I have a class which I need to modify (just a very tiny bit of it), which resides in `framework.dex` which was the part of `boot.oat`.

I have two questions:

1. How can I repack `boot.oat`? Taking into account that I haven't touch `boot.art`?
2. How can I make my change in `boot.oat` permanent? It's very well possible that I will install some new packages onto this system later, which will (might?) ruin my modification.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `boot.oat` is regenerated when a package is installed? I would have assumed that it is only regenerated after a system update has been installed.

Comment: I might misunderstood something, and yes, `boot.oat` might only be replaced during system update, which is unlikely for these old devices. Can you help me on Q1 please?

Comment: As far as I remember the original dex file is completely included in the oat file (or was it in the art file? don't really remember that). If it is use a hex editor, search for the [DEX_FILE_MAGIC](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format#dex-file-magic) and extract the dex file. Then decompilation should not be a problem.

Comment: Original DEX is in `boot.oat` (framework.dex). I need to modify a class in `framework.dex`, and put it back to `boot.oat`. But I've various information on rewriting header hash, or CRC or whatever.

Comment: Start to deodex with any kitchen, after that you can modify th framework.jar